# Get different rows from result of CTE expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a CTE like this:

```
DECLARE @LastDesigns AS TABLE
(
    [LegacyKey]       INT
    , [DesignKey]     INT
    , [Folio]         INT
    , [StatusKey]     INT
    , [DesignGroupId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

INSERT INTO @LastDesigns
    SELECT
        [P].[LegacyKey]
        , [D].[DesignKey]
        , [D].[Folio]
        , [D].[StatusKey]
        , [D].[DesignGroupId]
    FROM EbCorp.dbo.Project AS P
    INNER JOIN EbCorp.dbo.DesignGroup AS DG ON P.ProjectKey = DG.ProjectKey
    INNER JOIN EbCorp.dbo.Design AS D ON DG.DesignGroupId = D.DesignGroupId
    WHERE [D].[IsDeleted] = 0
        AND [ParentDesignGroupId] IS NULL;

WITH CTE2 (
    [LegacyKey]
    , [DesignKey]
    , [Folio]
    , [StatusKey]
    , [DesignGroupId]
    , [RN]
) AS (
    SELECT
        [LegacyKey]
        , [DesignKey]
        , [Folio]
        , [StatusKey]
        , [DesignGroupId]
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [LegacyKey], [DesignGroupId] ORDER BY [DesignKey] DESC) AS [RN]
    FROM @LastDesigns
)
SELECT
    [LegacyKey]
    , [DesignKey]
    , [Folio]
    , [StatusKey]
    , [DesignGroupId]
FROM CTE2
WHERE [RN] = 1;
```

This query returns info like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| LegacyKey | DesignKey | Folio | StatusKey |            DesignGroupId             |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|     18233 |      7540 |  5465 |        67 | 25687D54-B109-451B-9386-DD21C24ABBA9 |
|     18233 |      7543 |  5464 |        67 | 25687D54-B109-451B-9386-DD21C24ABBA9 |
|     18233 |      5229 |  4104 |       111 | 7E9F6DC9-6D1F-40DA-9D84-FE4D969A4289 |
|     18234 |      3920 |  2792 |        67 | 44D2DAFB-1880-4B93-AD04-2336B43E5BCA |
|     18234 |      7381 |  5306 |        67 | 7ADF74D6-A915-4882-9AC4-80FD801E9570 |
+-----------+-----------+-------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

We only concentrate on 2 columns: `LegacyKey` and `StatusKey`

As you can see first three rows have same `LegacyKey`, but one of them has different `StatusKey`.

I want only `LegacyKey` where one `StatusKey` is `67` and same `LegacyKey` have another row with different `StatusKey` of `67`, is that possible?

So in above example I only want

```
  18233 |      5229 |  4104 |       111 | 7E9F6DC9-6D1F-40DA-9D84-FE4D969A4289 |
```

Because this `LegacyKey` has another rows with `StatusKey` of `67` and ther last two rows are the same LegacyKey but both have `67` as `StatusKey` so I don't want it.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Do you mean you want only rows that aren't statuskey 67, as long as there is at least one other row with a statuskey of 67 and same legacykey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple/easy to understand approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE
  statuskey <> 67 and
  legacykey in (SELECT legacykey FROM cte WHERE statuskey= 67)
```

This builds a list of all the legacykeys with a statuskey of 67 then looks for all rows that are not statuskey 67 but do have a legacykey in that built list

This could also be done with joins, exists, even grouping, but for me the IN approach is probably easiest to read, understand and maintain